# Rails: conditions on *last* associated object for a collection of parent objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I've got the following setup:

```
class User 
    has_many :posts
end

class Post
    attr_accessible :post_type
end
```

What I would like to do, is to find all Users, whose *last* post is of a certain type.

Put differently, I'd like to do the equivalent of:

```
User.all.select do |u|
    u.posts.last.post_type == x
end
```

Where "x" is the post_type I'm looking for. Of course, this code snippet is ridiculously slow, so I'm looking for an ActiveRecord query that is much more performant.

Hope somebody can help me with this. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does anybody have a suggestion?

Comment: I have the same exact question. Did you ever figure it out?